# Trying to assign database information to ArrayList and then ListView

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-listview, cursor

So please bear with me on this one...  I am trying to get all information from my database table and output that information into a nice custom ListView (which I have already built).

**MySQLiteHelper.java** (What I am using to scrape the information)

```
...
public List<String> getAllLogs() {
        List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_GASLOG;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            List.add(cursor.getString(1));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return List;
}
...
```

**gasLog.java** (What I am using to get/set all of my information)

```
...
public class gasLog {

    private int id;
    private double pricePerGallon;
    private double gallons;
    private double odometer;
    private String date;
    private String filledOrNot; //This will be a 0 or 1 value.
    private String comments;

    public gasLog(){}

    public gasLog(double pricePerGallon, double gallons, double odometer, String date, String filledOrNot, String comments){
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.pricePerGallon = pricePerGallon;
        this.gallons = gallons;
        this.odometer = odometer;
        this.date = date;
        this.filledOrNot = filledOrNot;
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    //getters & setters


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getPricePerGallon() {
        return pricePerGallon;
    }

    public void setPricePerGallon(double pricePerGallon) {
        this.pricePerGallon = pricePerGallon;
    }

    public double getGallons(){
        return gallons;
    }

    public void setGallons(double gallons){
        this.gallons = gallons;
    }

    public double getOdometer(){
        return odometer;
    }

    public void setOdometer(double odometer){
        this.odometer = odometer;
    }

    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date){
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getFilledOrNot(){
        return filledOrNot;
    }

    public void setFilledOrNot(String filledOrNot){
        this.filledOrNot = filledOrNot;
    }

    public String getComments(){
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments){
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public String toString() {

        return "Date: " + date + ", Price: " + pricePerGallon + ", " + gallons + " Gallons, " + 
                ", Odometer Reading: " + odometer +
                ", Full fill: " + filledOrNot;
    }

}
```

**history.java** (Where I am inflating the view and calling all the information to).

```
...
public class history extends ListActivity {

        // Log table name
        private static final String TABLE_GASLOG = "gasLog";


        // Log table columns names
        private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        private static final String KEY_PRICE_PER_GALLON = "pricePerGallon";
        private static final String KEY_GALLONS = "gallons";
        private static final String KEY_ODOMETER = "odometer";
        private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
        private static final String KEY_FILLED_OR_NOT = "filledOrNot";
        private static final String KEY_COMMENTS = "comments";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Roboto-Light.ttf");

        ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        TextView history = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.history);
        history.setTypeface(tf);



        MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        List<gasLog> list = new ArrayList<gasLog>();
        list = db.getAllLogs();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listContent.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

So I know I need more in the bottom section of **history.java** Something similar to..

```
// THE DESIRED COLUMNS TO BE BOUND
            String[] columns = new String[] { People.NAME, People.NUMBER };
            // THE XML DEFINED VIEWS WHICH THE DATA WILL BE BOUND TO
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_entry, R.id.number_entry };
```

But I am not quite sure what everything should be.  I had tried using a getContentResolver but im not sure how to set the URI (or get the URI for my database) or if that is even the proper method to go.

my history.xml contains a listview and i have a bg.xml file that has the layout for each record in the listview.  Right now I can only get it to return the messy looking String toString() at the bottom of gasLog.java

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if someone could give me some direction and also maybe why?  Looking forward to learning something on this that I can apply down the road.  Thank you so much!  Sorry for being such a newbie!

EDIT:

Just want to make sure I am clear on this part.
in **GasCursorAdapter.java** I will setup bindView like this:

```
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor){
        TextView cardDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardDate);
        int date = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_DATE);
        cardDate.setText(date);
    }
```

and will do that for each view/db field (then that will assign the values to the view) (I think?!)

as far as this part goes, im not quite sure where to put that..

```
MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);    
Cursor cursor = db.getAllLogs();
        GasCursorAdapter adapter = new GasCursorAdapter(content, cursor, 0);
        setAdapter(adapter);
```

right now i have that in **history.java** but i am getting **content cannot be resolved to a variable**

Other than that i **think** i have it figured out thanks to you!!!

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You probably want to use a `CursorAdapter`, but that's another story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a CursorAdapter, which will skip a few of the steps and run much smoother. I was doing something similar to you, and ran into a lot of performance issues, but I switched to a cursorAdapter, and my code is much easier to follow and quicker as a result. There's a few parts to making this happen, which I'll show you below. The first step is to simply return the cursor, instead of trying to process it in your database call.

```
public Cursor getAllLogs() {
        List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_GASLOG;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

This will actually pass the query in a way that you can better utilize it. The way I managed my program was to do something like this from here.

1. Define what a row of output of the database should look like, and place in an XML file.
2. Set up a CursorAdapter that looks something like the code below.
3. Create your query, and then pass it to a new GasCursorAdapter.

Here's `GasCursorAdapter`

```
public class GasCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater=null;


    public GasCursorAdapter (Context context, Cursor c,int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        mInflater=(LayoutInflater) context
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gasLayout,parent,false);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View v,Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        //View is the view created by newView, take it and find your views and populate it, given the Cursor
    }

}
```

And creating it looks like:

```
Cursor cursor=getAllLogs();
GasCursorAdapter adapter=new GasCursorAdapter(context, cursor,0);
setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thank you Pearson!  This is what I am looking for and I'm going to try to implement this now.  Bear with me please as I may have a few questions along the way and will mark your answer accepted as soon as I finish the implementation...  I believe this is the feedback I needed so again, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Glad to spare you the pain of what I just went through.

Comment: Pearson, I posted an additional question if I could just get a little bit of clarification.  Thank you again so much!  I think im on my way there!

Comment: @Rob: There was a typo, I should have put context. I don't know where your getting it from, but you have to pipe a context to the Adapter creation.

Comment: Alright thank you.. I am going to do a bit more digging to try and understand exactly what needs to be there!